# Send a mail from web server using asp.net? Not working in Godaddy webserver

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a website, there is a `Contact Us` tab. User have to fill the form and when click the button I should get a mail from user.

It's working fine when I am running from localhost. But the same code it is not running in Godaddy webserver. This is my code

```
try
        {
            MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage("From@gmail.com", "To@mydomain.com");
            mailMessage.Subject = txtSubject.Text;

            string msg = "#Sender Name: " + txtUserName.Text + "#Sender Email ID: " + txtUserEmailId.Text + "#Company Name: " + txtCompanyName.Text + "#Mobile No: " + txtMobileNo.Text + "#Office Telephone No: " + txtOfficeTelephoneNo.Text + "#Office Fax No: " + txtOfficeFaxNo.Text + "#City: " + txtCity.Text + "#Sender Message: " + txtMessage.Text;
            string newMsg = msg.Replace("#", "\n");
            mailMessage.Body = newMsg;

            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);

            smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential()
            {
                UserName = "From@gmail.com",
                Password = "Password"
            };

            smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
            smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            Response.Write(ee.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Check if port number 587 is enabled on the server!

Comment: Turn On Access for less secure apps in the gmail account. see this link https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en-GB

Comment: @Am_I_Helppful :  How to check the port number 587 is enabled on server?.. please tell me

Comment: @Chirag: I Did that already, that's why i am getting email when i tried from local host

Comment: @mohamed faisal change port number 587 to 25.i hope it's work.

Comment: Change your port to 25

Comment: @ManishSingh : I changed and tried. It's worked in local host. but not in godaddy server

Comment: you have to use suuport of godday

Comment: @ManishSingh : Can you tell me how?. Please help me

Comment: @you should mail or call to support number.